# How can i integrate DynamoDB with amplify flutter such that any user can upload(write) data and this data is accessible(read) by all the users?

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am creating an android app with flutter. Now I want the user to be able to upload data to DynamoDb from the app. After then this data will be available to all the users. I'm not founding enough documentation on it

After configuring all the resources, I wrote this piece of code but it's not giving.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have a look at fine grained access control for DynamoDB using IAM permissions:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/fine-grained-access-control-for-amazon-dynamodb/